# Performant list of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, intrusive-containers

I have:

1. class X
2. boost::unordered_map of X
3. List of X - used to timeout element according to timestamp
4. I need to insert and remove element from list with performance.
   I though using intrusive list, so an element can remove itself from the list without going through all the list.
5. I want to wrap X with shared_ptr so it won't leak...

I discovered that shared_ptr is not compatible with intruive ptr.
1. Do you have another proposition?

Using multi_index of shared_ptr with 2 indexes(hashed and ordered) could be the best solution, but i can't use it.

2.Is oredered index in multi index efficient for removing element?

Comment: Is the list ordered by insertion time or do the timeouts come in some other order?  I.e. is it like every element dies after 5 seconds, or every element has a configurable timeout?

Comment: Since you'd be fine with an intrusive list, could the `X` object just store an iterator into the list?

Comment: @JohnZwinck The list is ordered at insertion time.

Comment: @Angew Do you mean to store an iterator to a regular list element? Is this legal?

Comment: Use `make_shared` and move the `shared_ptr`, then it's (almost) equivalent to a raw pointer. Will work with any kind of list or container. Copying a `shared_ptr` is expensive since it needs an atomic modification of the refcount. Moving doesn't change the number of references, so that's a simple binary copy of a two-pointer-sized structure.

Comment: @davidbobo Why should storing an iterator be illegal? `std::list` iterators are never invalidated as long as the element is actually in the list.